# PFQueryTableViewController not passing data to DetailsViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a PFQueryTableViewController that has a list of products (everything works perfectly) and when the cell is pressed a `DetailsViewController` is opened but the Details page is blank.

This is my PrepareToSegue method in the `PromosViewController.m` (and I did `#import "DetailsViewController.h"`):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"displayDetailFromList"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailsViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        Promos *promoDetail = [[Promos alloc] init];
        promoDetail.longName = [object objectForKey:@"longName"];
        destViewController.promoDetail = promoDetail;   
    }
}
```

In my `DetailsViewController.h` I have done:

```
@property (werk, nonatomic) Promos *promoDetail;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longLabel;
```

and the `DetailsViewController.m` I have:

```
self.longLabel.text = promoDetail.longName;
self.title = @"Product";
```

but when I run my application and pressed the cell the label is empty and does not show anything (i get a blank screen with the navigation bar and title "Product").

What am I doing wrong and why is my data not transferring to the DetailsViewController?

Comment: Do a NSLog on promoDetail.longName in your prepareForSegue method. Does it have any value?

Comment: I actually fixed it by changing the property from weak to retain, I was going to post that I fixed it but it wouldn't let me because I don't have enough points, but thanks for the answer ;) @kentoh